# How to iterate through the Datagrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid view in my WPF .Where i map an item source in it.Datagrid view contains checkboxes in all rows.User may check or uncheck some rows.So i want to iterate through the datagrid row and cell values to know the selected rows .I tried all things present in Internet but nothing helps.please help me to solve my pbm

Comment: Best way to get help is to provide some code. Like your current not working progress. You can easily get the selected Items `dataGrid.selectedItems`. But further information would help us to help you... e.g.: where do you want to get the selection? What is your architecture like? Want you to have the selection in CodeBehind or XAML?...

Answer (score -1):

Begin with reading about MVVM pattern.

You need a model. That should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. And each property setter should call OnPropertyChanged() method. Implementation I leave to you.

```
   public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

You need a view-model.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> MyList { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyList = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        MyList.Add(new Model() { Name = "John", IsChecked = true });
        MyList.Add(new Model() { Name = "Bety", IsChecked = false });
        MyList.Add(new Model() { Name = "Samuel", IsChecked = true });
    }
}
```

And right bindings in the view.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel></local:ViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" Binding="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And then you iterate the MyList in the view-model and do what you want to do with Checked/Unchecked items.